# taekwondo injury

Tags: tae-kwon-do, injury

I was injured last August in my taekwondo training. My foot was casted because there has been a little crack on my 2nd-3rd metatarsal and it was taken off last September. I really REALLY want to train again, but I'm still afraid and nervous. I'm stretching here at home and still taking vitamins for the bones. When do I get to train again? (it's my 4th month since the injury) :(

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please check out the [help] to see how we work. Sadly, this is very much a medical advise question which are off topic since we are martial arts experts and not medical doctors. *You should consult your physician and direct all question at them.* Do **not** trust strangers on the Internet (no matter how many fake points they have) with your health.

Comment: If you were to edit your question so that it was asking about tae-kwon-do specific exercises to avoid this type of injury, that would be a fine question.

Comment: [Off to meta!…](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/530/82)

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the medical issues, I can offer some ideas for you to do while you are on the mend.  How you achieve "on the mend" is out of scope for this site (medical advice), but what you can do **while**, rather then **for**, being on the mend is a very different thing.

Here are some things you can do:

1. Be a patient, and be patient

Read:

2. Like a textbook or encyclopedia about your style (see links)
3. From authors writing about your style (eg, Sang Kim, Dr Kyu Hung Lee)
4. About other styles (eg Dr Jwing Ming Yang)
5. About healing methods and injury avoidance
6. About stretching (eg, Tom Kurz)
7. Other ("The Way of Kata" (Kane, Wilder); Sun Tzu; others)

Watch:

8. Videos on forms and applications (Iain Abernethy, John Burke)
9. Competitive-grade performance for board breaking and forms, maybe you can get ideas on using their technique?

Research:

10. Meaning of advancement in your style
11. Terms and phrases in Taekwondo

Other:

12. Learn basic Korean
13. Ask the instructor how you might help the dojang while you are on the mend

Good luck, and feel better!

[The Way of Kata](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594390584)

[Kukkiwon Taekwondo Textbook (Korean-English)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8973367501)

[Complete Taekwondo Poomsae: The Official Taegeuk, Palgwae and Black Belt Forms of Taekwondo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00POFH6BC)

[Tai Chi Chuan Martial Power: Advanced Yang Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594392943)

[Simple Qigong Exercises for Health: Improve Your Health in 10 to 20 Minutes a Day](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594392692)

[Sports Training Info for Serious Athletes](http://www.stadion.com)

Comment: I'd add, that while visualization exercises aren't nearly as useful as some trainers sell them to be, if you have a decent imagination, visualizing yourself going through movements can be useful to keep yourself from getting rusty. Sure, it doesn't help much with muscle tone, but it helps keep fresh all of those little tweaks that you've learned that aren't in the textbook.